# Adjoint of the following operator: $B: L_2[0,1]\to L_2[0,1]; B(x(t))=e^tx(\sqrt t)$

Tags: functional-analysis, adjoint-operators

Adjoint of the following operator:$$B: L_2[0,1]\to L_2[0,1];  \\ B(x(t))=e^tx(\sqrt t)$$

This is what I have tried: 
Using the knowledge that

> $$<Bx,y^*>=<x,B^*y^*>$$

I have that :
$$<Bx,y^*> = \int_{0}^{1}(Bx)(t)y^*(t)dt=\int_{0}^{1}e^tx(\sqrt t)y^*(t)dt=\int_{0}^{1}x(\sqrt t)e^ty^*(t)dt$$
and also:
$$<x,B^*y^*> = \int_{0}^{1}x(t)(B^*y^*)(t)dt$$

This square root is messing this up, and I do not know how to finish. If in both integrals it was $x(t)$ this would be a peice of cake. But looking at this as it is, I don't know what to do!

Comment: since when do nonlinear operators necessarily have adjoints? Certainly they cannot be members of the dual space.

Comment: How about a substitution $u=\sqrt{t}$ in the last integral? That leads to $$\int_0^1e^{u^2}2u\overline{y(u^2)} x(u)du$$ from which the adjoint pops right out.

Comment: Hey thanks man!